# Standards in P.L. Topology

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, compact-manifolds

About a week ago, the reading course on PL topology I'm going to follow started. The aim of the reading course is to understand the basics of PL topology and have a reasonable to good understanding of the main results of this field of research (e.g. Kirby-Siebenmann). The main references for this course are the books by Hudson and by Rourke-Sanderson, from the late sixties and the early seventies. (with names that should make it clear they're dealing with PL manifolds)

When comparing the basic definitions, it quickly became clear that there are quite some differences between these books. Polyhedra in the Rourke-Sanderson case may, for instance, be rather 'wobbly'. The question arising from this is whether some standard has been established on these definitions and if so, where to find it. Is there really one book that should be considered the basis for these things?